# Should we have separate tags for license versions?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We currently have [gpl](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gpl), [gpl-2](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gpl-2) and [gpl-3](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gpl-3) tags. Is it useful and helpful to have these tags, or should we stick to only one tag for all versions. If we shouldn't, then can we make them synonyms?

A related question is whether the individual Creative Commons licenses should get their own tags or not.

Answer (score 2):

With no volume, they should be synonyms. We can de-synonymize it once the need arises. In your case, we only need:

[gpl](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gpl) <- [gpl2](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gpl2) <- [gpl3](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gpl3)

Answer (score 2):

The topics of compatibility and incompatiblity of GPLv2 and GPLv3 and the difference of licensing under GPLv2-only or GPLv2-or-later are possible.

But I'm not sure if they are relevant enough to warrant individual tags for each license version.